# Formatting options are not displaying for rich text editor in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Formatting options are not displaying for rich text editor in sharepoint 2013 in chrome & firefox browsers....but displaying in IE...can anyone help me out

Answer (score 0):

In earlier versions of SharePoint, it was available right above the rich text box in the form of menu bar and that was supported only in IE browser.

But now in SharePoint 2013, fomatting options of rich text editor are available in the ribbon under `Format Text` and `Insert` tab. These tab controls are visible as soon as user clicks on Rich text box.

These Tab controls are supported in IE, Chrome and also Firebox browser.

Check if you have customized master page with custom CSS/Scripts or there are any errors in page which you can check in browser console.

Check out these links for more info on this.

[SharePoint Rich Text Editor not working in Firefox and Chrome](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c6482efb-72e1-4536-a3cb-153d838744a4/sharepoint-rich-text-editor-not-working-in-firefox-and-chrome?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)

[Multiple lines of text rich text editor not working chrome](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/124917/multiple-lines-of-text-rich-text-editor-not-working-chrome)

Comment: Thanks bro and it is not a enhanced rich text editor, it is rich text editor. I created a new site and an announcement with description of RTE. there is no css files its a purely new site.